# What is the best approach for quick fix the errors/bugs in phase1 code through the DevOps?

Tags: devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, devops-services

I have two branches like **dev** and **master** in VSTS to manage my code. After completed phase 1 development, I have published my web application code from master branch through my Dev Ops configuration.

But every day we do pull request from **dev** to **master**, so every day master having latest code.

I have doubt like

After completed phase 1, my development team will started to work on phase 2 development on **dev** branch. But at some point time customers will raise the bugs/errors on phase 1 release of web application at that time how to quick fix those issues of phase 1 web application without interrupting the phase 2 development already started.
Can you please tell what is the best approach to quick fix the errors/bugs in phase 1 and how to release only phase 1 code after fixed the errors/bugs.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a new branch (e.g. devPhase2) from master after phase, then to work on phase2 with this new branch. After that, you can fix the bugs on old branch (e.g. dev) and merge to master and release. After phase 2 finishing, merge DevPhase2 branch to master and release.

You also can fix the issue in phase and release phase 2 with fixed bugs of phase during release phase 2.